# Android: VerticalGridFragment cause app to crash when using ErrorFragment?

Tags: java, android, android-tv

I've seen many questions regarding `Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment` but none of them is related to mine and even trying some of the solutions did not work.

My issue is that when I'm using a `VerticalGridFragment` and I present an `ErrorFragment` it crashes. However, if I extend my `MainFragment` to use `DetailsFragment`, the app does not crash and I am able to use the `ErrorFragment`.

Here's my sample code:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_browse_fragment"
    android:name="com.ui.MainFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ui.MainActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="tv"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

MainFragment.java:

```
public class MainFragment extends VerticalGridFragment
{
    public final ErrorFragment error = new ErrorFragment();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        displayInternetError();
    }

    public void displayInternetError()
    {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_browse_fragment, error)
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();

        error.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lb_ic_sad_cloud, null));
        error.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet_message));
        error.setDefaultBackground(true);

        error.setButtonText(getResources().getString(R.string.retry_connection));

        error.setButtonClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {

            }
        });
    }

    ...
}
```

My Logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.vietmytv_androidtv, PID: 17619
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vietmytv_androidtv/com.example.vietmytv_androidtv.ui.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                    
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)        
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
    at com.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)        
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)         
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
    at com.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v17.leanback.widget.VerticalGridPresenter$ViewHolder android.support.v17.leanback.widget.VerticalGridPresenter.onCreateViewHolder(android.view.ViewGroup)' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v17.leanback.app.VerticalGridFragment.onViewCreated(VerticalGridFragment.java:170)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:954)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126) 
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1228)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2201)
    at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5546)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
    at com.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Based on how I display my layout, I need to use `VerticalGridLayout`, but I'm not sure how to use it with `ErrorFragment`.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Somehitng is not set and it is causing a null pointer exception in android.support.v17.leanback.app.VerticalGridFragment.onViewCreated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look with caution the logcat, you can see that problem is not related to XML but to some method called during XML inflation (probably some callBack method).

**ERROR**

So, error is possible here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v17.leanback.widget.VerticalGridPresenter$ViewHolder android.support.v17.leanback.widget.VerticalGridPresenter.onCreateViewHolder(android.view.ViewGroup)' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v17.leanback.app.VerticalGridFragment.onViewCreated(VerticalGridFragment.java:170)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:954)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126) 
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1228)
```

**mGridPresenter is NULL**

I checked the source code of `android.support.v17.leanback.app.VerticalGridFragment` [HERE](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.1_r1/android/support/v17/leanback/app/VerticalGridFragment.java):

You can confirm that method `VerticalGridFragment.onViewCreated()` calls `VerticalGridPresenter.onCreateViewHolder()`

```
@Override
public void More ...onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup gridDock = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.browse_grid_dock);
    mGridViewHolder = mGridPresenter.onCreateViewHolder(gridDock);
    gridDock.addView(mGridViewHolder.view);

    updateAdapter();
}
```

However, according to log, at that time, `onCreateViewHolder` is called in a `NULL` reference

So, we can conclude that `mGridPresenter` is `NULL`

**How to fix**

Checking `android.support.v17.leanback.app.VerticalGridFragment` souce code, you can see that `mGridPresenter` is set only in method `setGridPresenter()`.

```
public void setGridPresenter(VerticalGridPresenter gridPresenter) {
    if (gridPresenter == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Grid presenter may not be null");
    }
    mGridPresenter = gridPresenter;
    ...
}
```

So, probably, you have to call that method before use the `VerticalGridFragmet`

Checking this example from Google ([HERE](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SupportLeanbackDemos/src/com/example/android/leanback/VerticalGridFragment.java)), you can see that they call `setGridPresenter()`. So, maybe, you missing that step.

```
private void setupFragment() {
    VerticalGridPresenter gridPresenter = new VerticalGridPresenter();
    gridPresenter.setNumberOfColumns(NUM_COLUMNS);
    setGridPresenter(gridPresenter);
...
```

**This does not complete answer your question... But I think it help you to find the way...**

Regards